# Filtering table with a JCheckBox column

Tags: java, jtable, filtering

I have a JTable with 6 columns. The first column is a JCheckBox column. I created a search box to filter the table through this code :

```
String searchWord = searchTextField.getText();
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>( myTable.getModel() );
myTable.setRowSorter( sorter );
sorter.setRowFilter( RowFilter.regexFilter( searchWord );
```

The problem is if user searched for "true", "false", "t", "se", ... it returns the rows having check boxes enabled or disabled ... I guess it deals with their value as true/false.

**So is there a way to ignore the first column while filtering the table ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the regexFilter which columns you want to check. Say you have five columns in your table, and the first one is the JCheckBox column, then you can ignore it by using:

```
sorter.setRowFilter( RowFilter.regexFilter( searchWord, 1, 2, 3, 4 ) );
```

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29) for `RowFilter`:

> **regexFilter**
>
> `public static <M,I> RowFilter<M,I> regexFilter(String regex, int... indices)`
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> regex - the regular expression to filter on
>
> indices - the indices of the values to check. If not supplied all
>   values are evaluated

Comment: Was about to tell him the same ;) (+1)

Comment: @Thomas: I was going to tell the same thing too :). After just sending my question i looked in the API and found it before checking this answer. At first i didn't understand what indices, but when i tried it, it worked. Thanks a lot.